# Upwards tangent vector of triangle in 3D space

Tags: vector, 3d, geometry, normals

I have a triangle in 3D cartesian space, it forms a surface. I have a normal vector of that surface. What I want to find out, is a vector tangent to that surface, which points the most "upwards". (The orange one on image, forgive my paint skills) [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let one triangle edge vector is **A**. Get perpendicular vector in the plane

```
P = N x A
```

and normalize **P** and **A**

```
p = P / len(P)    
a = A / len(A)
```

Any unit vector in the plane is combination of these base vectors

```
v = p * cos(t) + a * sin(t)      (1)
```

We want that Z-component of **v** to be maximal (as far as I understand `most "upwards"`)

```
vz = pz * cos(t) + az * sin(t)    (2)
```

has extremum when it's derivative by t is zero

```
0 = (pz * cos(t) + az * sin(t))' = -pz * sin(t) + az * cos(t)
tan(t) = az / pz
t = atan2(az , pz)
```

put `t` values into (1) and get needed vector **v**

Comment: Thanks for a great explanation, however by "most upwards" I meant a vector **v** which is the closest to **y** = (0, 1, 0) (assuming y is up) in terms of an angle between them (**y** and **v**)

Comment: Actually, after thinking about it, if we talk about normalized vectors, the one with max z is going to be the one I'm talking about, so thanks!

Comment: Just change z-component to y-one